# Как обновить размер диска в гостевой ubuntu после увеличения виртуального диска .vdi в vbox?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, lvm, fdisk

Запускаю команду
`~$ VBoxManage modifyhd ~/"VirtualBox VMs"/BOX/production/export_2018.10.15-2018.10.15-disk001.vdi --resize 120000 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В гостевой ubuntu parted и fdisk показывают разные результаты, выделенная свободная память не отображается.

```
# lsblk
NAME                       MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                          8:0    0  100G  0 disk 
├─sda1                       8:1    0  487M  0 part /boot
├─sda2                       8:2    0    1K  0 part 
└─sda5                       8:5    0 99,5G  0 part 
  ├─planbox--vg-root   252:0    0 97,5G  0 lvm  /
  └─planbox--vg-swap_1 252:1    0    2G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sr0                         11:0    1 1024M  0 rom  

# parted /dev/sda
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) p                                                                
Model: ATA VBOX HARDDISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 107GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  512MB  511MB  primary   ext2         boot
 2      513MB   107GB  107GB  extended
 5      513MB   107GB  107GB  logical                lvm


# fdisk /dev/sda

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.27.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sda: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x90fb703d

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048    999423    997376  487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1001470 209713151 208711682 99,5G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1001472 209713151 208711680 99,5G 8e Linux LVM
```

При попытке добавить новый раздел, ругается, мол нет свободных секторов, иди...
Подскажите где копать? Наведите на путь истинный, ибо второй день пошел.

Comment: первое, что приходит на ум — не тот диск изменил...

Answer (score 1):

Ответ

1. Не сохраняя состояние, выключить машину или сбросить состояние машины
2. Изменить размер .vdi
3. В VBox открыть менеджер дисков(ctrl+d), выбрать нужный диск и обновить
4. Запустить машину и в гостевой ОС расширить раздел